# Build and use custom scala-library to extend primitive datatypes

Tags: scala, ant, compiler-errors, final

For a research prototype, I want to be able to extend primitive Scala datatypes (e.g., `Double`) with additional fields. This is not possible out-of-the-box because `scala.Double` and `scala.runtime.RichDouble` are declared `final`.

This is what I've tried:

1. Clone the scala repository
2. Remove the `final` modifier from class `scala.runtime.RichDouble` in file `src/library/scala/runtime/RichDouble.scala`
3. Compile Scala using ant: `ant build-opt`
4. Create a custom class extending `RichDouble`:

   `$ echo "class MyDouble extends scala.runtime.RichDouble {}" > MyDouble.scala`
5. Compile `MyDouble.scala` using the custom-compiled scala:

   `$ build/pack/bin/scalac MyDouble.scala`

This, however, results in the following error:

> MyDouble.scala:1: error: illegal inheritance from final class RichDouble class

Running with `strace`, the custom compiled `scala-library.jar` is indeed being loaded:

```
$ strace -f ./build/pack/bin/scalac MyDouble.scala 2>&1 | grep scala-library
stat("/my/custom/dir/scala/build/pack/lib/scala-library.jar", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5682113, ...}) = 0
```

What am I missing? Why is class `RichDouble` still reported as `final` even though I removed the modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to do is not possible. Primitive types such as `Double` are implemented as [value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), which are implicitly `final`. As such, it is one of their [essential limitations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#summary-of-limitations) that they can not be extended.

Comment: Florian, the obvious question is why you "rich" types have to inherit from the standard value classes? Why not use approach used for `BigInt` and other similar types where your "rich" types are actually usual classes implementing some traits/interfaces such as `Number`?

Comment: Hey, that is a good point and I did not mention this: I am integrating with the Spark framework which actually uses `RichDouble` etc. I want to refrain from modifying large parts of the existing codebase.

Comment: Well, I think you are out of luck then. I think Spark uses standard value types for performance reasons. For types like `Float` or `Double` all standard operations are guaranteed to be interpreted with just a single ASM instruction rather than much more expensive call of some method (via interface).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [implicit classes](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example): they are designed to extend closed classes.

```
implicit class MyDouble(d: Double) {
  def myNewFeature() = println("MyDouble is $d")
}
val d1 = new Double(42) // just instantiate a Double
d1.myNewFeature() // scala will do implicit conversion
```

Comment: I know about implicit classes. However, they won't let me add a new field that will also be serialized upon serialization of the object.